# Finding the Probability of an Event Happening in a Sphere, where a Point's Individual Probability Depends on its Distance from the Center

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm working on a pet project and I've reached a sticking point, I'll describe the problem, then I'll describe the direction I've been trying.

We have a sphere of radius $R$, filled with $N$ points. I don't think it matters, but $N$ is very high. Each point has probability of an event $E$ occurring that depends on it's distance from the sphere's center $r$, given by the function $P_{E}(r)$. All points are independent.

If it helps, here's a little diagram I whipped up:[Sphere Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HVR8.png)

Since we know the volume of the sphere and the number of point contained, we know the density of points, which we'll call $D$. The distribution of points is both homogeneous and isotropic, so the density remains constant for any local volume of the sphere.

What I'd like to know is, **what is the probability of the event $E$ happening at least once in the sphere?**

So far, my approach has been to split the sphere evenly, into concentric shells $\Delta r$ apart. Find what the number of points in this band is and ,assuming that all the points lie on the inner shell, workout the probability of $E$ occurring at least once. Using the probabilities of each band it should be possible to find the probability of the whole sphere. Getting an answer for this discrete version of the problem should allow us to send $\Delta r$ to the limit of $0$ resulting in some kind of integral? But this is where I'm struggling.

This is my first time asking a question here, so please let me know if I should provide any more information. Thanks for any help anyone can offer:)

Comment: Since this is a finite problem, just multiply.  The probability that all the points fail is $\prod_q  (1-P(q))$ where $q$ runs through the points in your sphere.  The bit about the distance might make it easier to compute that product, or it might not matter much.  It depends on the collection of points.

Comment: Not sure what sort of limit you hope for...There are uncountably many points a distance $r$ from the center (for a positive $r$), and since $P$ is constant on that inner shell,  the probability that the event fails on the entirety of the shell is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E_i$ that event happens at point $i$. We know (if I got it right) that $$P(E)= P(\cup E_i)= 1- P(\cap E_i^c) = 1 - (1-P(E_i))^N\tag1$$

And (assuming we are speaking of a 3D sphere) $$P(E_i) = \int P(E_i | r_i) \, p(r_i) \,d r_i = \frac{3}{R^3} \int_0^R P_E(r) \, r^2 dr \tag2$$

If the sphere is $D-$dimensional the integral is

$$ \frac{D}{R^D} \int_0^R P_E(r) \, r^{D-1} dr $$

---

Added: in more detail

Let's define the random variables

- $R_i$ (taking values in $[0,R]$) : distance from origin of point $i$
- $X_i=1$ if the event happens at point $i$, $0$ elsewhere.

What we are given is the conditional probability $P(X_i = 1 |  R_i = r) = P_E(r)$

Because $R_i$ is a continuous variable, we can write its density function $f_{R_i}(r) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} P(r\le R_i < r +h)$

We also know $f_{R_i}(r) \propto r^2 \implies f_{R_i}(r) = \frac{3}{R^3} r^2 $

Using the total law of probability:

$$P(E_i)= P(X_i=1) = \int P(X_i =1 | R_i  = r) f_{R_i}(r) dr $$

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you did there. $(1-P(E_1))\cdot(1-P(E_2))\cdot...\cdot(1-P(E_N))\neq(1-P(E_i))^n$ unless $P(E_i)$ is the same for every $i$, which is not since $P(E_i)=P_E(r)$ and different points $i$ may and usually will have different distances from the center $r$

Comment: Your reasoning would apply to $P(E_i|r_i)$, but if we don't know a prior the position of each point, each must have the same overall probability, which I calculated in $(2)$

Comment: You mean that, in your answer, $P(E_i)$ is not the probability that the event $E$ happens at a specific point $i$, but at a randomly selected point? Like a weighted average probability, weighted by the proportion of points at each distance of the center (which would be $\frac{3r^2}{R^3}$). If so, it kind of makes sense. I need to analyze it a bit harder to fully grasp it.

Comment: No, $P(E_i)$ is the probability for point $i$. It should be clear that $P(E_1) = P(E_2)$ , because the points are probabilistic equivalent.
But, you might say, the probababilities should be different if we know the distance ($r_i$)  of each point. Of course, but we don't know it, $r_i$ is a random variable. That's taken into account, applying the total law of total probability https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability#Continuous_case

Comment: Not sure why you said "no". I think we are saying the same thing. If, without knowing their $r_i$, all the $P(E_i)$ are the same, then for ANY point $i$ its probability will be $P(E_i)$ and hence that will be the probability for a randomly selected point. Furthermore, the link that you posted states "The summation can be interpreted as a weighted average, and consequently the marginal probability, $P(A)$, is sometimes called "average probability"". Note that said "summation" is what becomes an integral in the continuous case. I may be misunderstanding something though. I am no expert at all.

Comment: I said "no" because $P(E_i)$   _is_  the probability that the event $E$  happens at a specific point $i$